# JavaScript não encontra página em Aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação em ASPX e C#. Dentro do diretório "Scripts" da aplicação, tenho um `js` com o seguinte código:

```
function RecuperaDados(valor){
  loadXMLDoc("../Views/Home/Contact.aspx?ID="+valor);
}
```

No entanto, ele está retornando erro "404 -Not Found", só que essa página "Contact" está dentro do diretório "Home" que está dentro de "`Views". 
O que posso estar fazendo de errado ?!

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo uma [requisição HTTP do tipo GET](http://simplesideias.com.br/entendendo-um-pouco-mais-sobre-o-protocolo-http), o que significa que especificar um caminho de arquivos é ilegal e não vai funcionar.

Portanto, a sua função [loadXMLDoc](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp) não vai ter outro retorno enquanto você não especificar uma ação.

**Como assim?**

Se você já não tem, então crie um método para `Contact` no seu controlador `Home`. Algo assim:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [...]

    public ActionResult Contact(int id)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
}
```

Depois, na sua função loadXMLDoc, passe como parâmetro `"/Home/Contact?id=" + valor`, dessa forma:

```
function RecuperaDados(valor){
  loadXMLDoc("/Home/Contact?id=" + valor);
}
```

**O que aconteceu? Qual a diferença?**

Requisições GET feitas com AJAX solicitam por um retorno de tipo equivalente – HTTP, no caso –, e você estava lidando com um endereço de arquivo, o que, como já dito, não vai funcionar. Então, criamos uma ação no seu controlador `Home`, chamada `Contact`, para renderizarmos a sua view `Contact.aspx` (você já viu [Razor](http://www.microsoft.com/web/category/razor)?) como resposta à uma requisição GET no protocolo HTTP.

Dessa forma, conseguimos solucionar o seu problema atendendo a especificação da requisição do AJAX.